# Golang: Use one value in conditional from function returning multiple arguments

Tags: go

Suppose in Go we have a function returning two arguments

```
func squareAndCube(int side) (square int, cube int) {
    square = side * side
    cube = square * side
    return
}
```

Then you would like to use the first (second) value of this function in the conditional:

```
square, _ := squareAndCube(n)
if square > m {
    ...
}
```

However, can we do first two lines in one line if we do not need the value square to use anywhere else? E.g.

```
 if squareAndCube(n).First() > m {
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You cannot pick one of the multiple returned values but you can write something like

```
if square, _ := squareAndCube(n); square > m {
    // ...
}
```

The `square` variable will only be valid in the `if` scope. These "simple statements" can be used in [`if` statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements), [`switch` statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) and other constructs such as `for` loops.

See also the [effective go article on `if` statements](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if).

Answer (score 9):

Found [this](http://blog.vladimirvivien.com/2014/03/hacking-go-filter-values-from-multi.html) blog post by Vladimir Vivien that has a <s>nice</s> workaround for the problem. The solution is to create a function that "...exploits the automatic conversion from the compiler to convert a vararg parameters in the form of "x...interface{}" to a standard []interface{}."

```
func mu(a ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return a
}
```

Now you can wrap any function with multiple returned values in `mu` and index the returned slice followed by a type assertion

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

func mu(a ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return a
}

func myFunc(a,b string) (string, string){
    return b, a
}

func main(){
    fmt.Println(mu(myFunc("Hello", "World"))[1].(string))
}

// output: Hello
```

EDIT: See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911993/golang-use-one-value-in-conditional-from-function-returning-multiple-arguments/50346080#comment104801528_50346080) by [Matt Mc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700471/matt-mc)

Comment: Yeah, it's definetily not the most elegant solution :P